# Copy value from active sheet to new excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a work sheet named Final_Sheet, I want to create a button on that sheet and execute the following operation

Select Cell Range A1:D30 and pickup the values from cell only and create a new Excel file and paste the copied cell values into Sheet1 of created excel file. I am able to o this much, further I can't understand what to do can anybody please help me out?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
Dim rownum As Integer
Dim selection As Range

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

rownum = InputBox("Row No to Copy :", "OK")
selection = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rownum, 10)).Select
selection.Copy


Flname = InputBox("Enter File Name :", "Creating New File...")

MsgBox ("Output File Created Successfully")
If Flname <> "" Then
    Set NewWkbk = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D1:D30").Copy Before:=NewWkbk.Sheets(1)
    NewWkbk.Sheet(1).Select
    Cells(1, 1).Activate
    selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    NewWkbk.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Flname

    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should do as you've asked.

**EDIT: Pastes values only**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    'Dim Variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wbNew As Workbook, wbCurrent As Workbook
    Dim strFileName As String

    'Assign object variables
    Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wbCurrent.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:D30") 'Amend range if needed

    'Get desired file path from user
    strFileName = InputBox("Enter File Name: ", "Creating New File...")
    If strFileName <> "" Then
        'Create new Workbook and paste rng into it
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
        rng.Copy
        wbNew.Sheets(1).Range("A1:D30").PasteSpecial xlValues

        'Save new workbook using desired filepath
        wbNew.SaveAs wbCurrent.Path & "\" & strFileName
    End If
End Sub
```

It wasn't clear to me from the question which workbook you wished to close with `ActiveWorkbook.Close` but you could easily add `wbNew.Close` or `wbCurrent.Close` below `wbNew.SaveAs ...` as required.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, Its working, but I want only cell values not the formulas

Comment: how can I add paste Special for values only

Comment: Updated my answer to use PasteSpecial

Comment: Great to hear, if you found the answer helpful please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it. :)